# What provably fair Bitcoin gambling sites work well on a mobile?

Tags: mobile, gambling, gaming

Are there an Bitcoin-based gambling sites or apps that work on a mobile?

Most of the sites seem to be assuming the player is on a full size display.

If the service isn't considered "provably fair" then I'm not interested.  An example of a provably fair game is one where the host gives the hash of the secret, then a client seed is generated, then after play at some point the secret that was used is revealed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provably fair means the player can prove the operator didn't cheat.  With website-based provably fair systems, the generation of a random number and/or client seed is easily to see and monitor.  Unless a mobile app is open source, this same capability is not available.

So a provably fair website that provides an app doesn't mean the app provides provably fair online gaming as well.   An open source app could be provably fair.

You won't find any of (or at least not many of) these apps on the Google Play store since they are online gambling that is a prohibited app on their service.  But the apps can still be installed from external sources:

- Seals With Club poker has a mobile app.
- Bitcoin Video Casino has [an Android app](https://bitcoinvideocasino.com/android).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, SatoshiDice doesn't need anything except a wallet.  You send your bet to a certain fixed address (which you could add to your address book) and then your winnings are sent back to your address.

Granted, there isn't really a game to play in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You can see a list of verified "provably fair" Bitcoin casino sites, here:

http://provablyfair.org

"Provably Fair Gaming means you can verify each played to ensure you always get a fair deal. Modern cryptographic algorithms hash algorithms compute the fair random number based on data from the blockchain."

Depending on the type of games you like, you can find what you are looking for.

I like Roulette, so I play Bitcoin Roulette:

http://Bitcoin-Roulette.com

This is the algo they use:

The pseudo-code: 
$hash = TRANSFER_ID;
$secret_key = SECRET_KEY;

$finalhash = hash_hmac('sha512', $hash . $secret_key);

$temphash  = substr($finalhash, 0, 4);          // get 4-bytes of final SHA256 hash
$converted = base_convert($temphash,16,10);     // convert to integer

$final_answer = $converted % 36;            // get a number from 0 -> 36

Answer (score 0):

[Coin Controller](https://coincontroller.com/) is a provably fair game and works on mobile devices as well. Its a little bit different than most traditional gambling games, but its a nice easy way to win some extra coins, and there is an awesome affiliate program.

Check it out, better explanation and details on how to play on the site. Also, accepts Litecoins and Bitcoins.

Answer (score -1):

[DoubleDownBTC](https://doubledownbtc.com) has a mobile friendly version and looks great on iPads or phones.  The problem with most native apps is the legal grey area of Bitcoin gambling.  There are some self published android apps out there, but I'm a little nervous about malware, etc.  The mobile optimized websites seem like a better choice.

Comment: Your answer doesn't fit the question, as this is about provable fair gambling.

Comment: DoubleDownBTC claims to be provably fair so I think this is a valid answer.